# Equation of lines through origin and two vectors

Tags: vectors

Question: Find the equation of the form ax+by+cz=d whose graph is the plane through the origin gneerated by <4,-1,2> and <-1,0,4>.

I'm not sure where to start, and I don't whether to use cross and dot product.

Comment: One way: A point on the plane is a linear combination of the 2 vectors. You then have x, y and z on the plane in terms of two parameters, say s and t. Your first relation might be $x = 4s - 1t$, so what would y and z be? Now find s and t in terms of x and y then substitute those into the equation for z. No need for dot or cross products.

Comment: Surely there’s an example of how to do this in the course material leading up to this exercise. Start there.